# pLimit giving me a list of undefined promises

Tags: node.js, p-limit

```
        const maxParallelRequests = 1;
        const limit = pLimit(maxParallelRequests);

        // Use the map method to create an array of promises for each call to GetData
        const promises = items.map(item => {
            limit(() => this.getData(item))
        });
```

When I log `promises` I get an array of 60 `undefined` items.

What am I doing wrong  here?

`item` is defined inside the map function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add return in the map:

```
        // Use the map method to create an array of promises for each call to GetData
        const promises = items.map(item => {
            return limit(() => this.getData(item))
        });
```